# Unable to Restore SQL Database from same server and Rename it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to restore databases from the same server and give new name. Below is working code. How to make it?

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [Mallesh4000] FROM  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\MALLESH' WITH  FILE = 1,
MOVE N'RSSQ001' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Mallesh4000.mdf', 
MOVE N'RSSQ001_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Mallesh4000_log.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
GO
```

Below code not working how to make it dynamic.
Like new DB Name, MDFpath,LDFpath

```
Declare @dbname Varchar(50)
Declare @DBpath VarChar(500)
Declare @mdfpath varchar(500)
Declare @ldfpath varchar(500)

Set @DBNAME = 'Mallesh6000'

Set  @DBname  = [@DBNAME]
Set  @DBpath  = N 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\MALLESH'
Set  @mdfPath = N 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\'+@dbname+'.mdf'
Set  @ldfpath = N 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\'+@dbname+'_log.ldf'

print @DBname
print @DBpath
print @mdfPath
print @ldfpath


USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [@dbname] FROM 
DISK = @DBpath WITH  FILE = 1
MOVE N'RSSQ001' TO @mdfPath, 
MOVE N'RSSQ001_log' TO @ldfpath,
NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
GO
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is always a little bit of work that goes into backing up and restoring databases, especially when trying to change naming/conventions ..  The easiest way is going to be a powershell script, or a bash script that backs the database up to the physical (SQL) file, then does a `sed`-`grep`/`find-replace` on that file afterward changing your database name in the file itself -- So when restored it uses the new database name.

Answer (score 0):

Close.  As a delimited identifier `[@dbname]` would restore the database with the name "@dbname", and you're missing a couple of commas.

This:

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [@dbname] FROM 
DISK = @DBpath WITH  FILE = 1
MOVE N'RSSQ001' TO @mdfPath, 
MOVE N'RSSQ001_log' TO @ldfpath,
NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
```

should be

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE @DBname
FROM DISK = @DBpath
WITH  FILE = 1,
MOVE N'RSSQ001' TO @mdfPath,
MOVE N'RSSQ001_log' TO @ldfpath,
NOUNLOAD,  
STATS = 5
```